# Refresh url menuitem navigation primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a problem with url refreshing after clicking on a menuItem.

I have a dataTable with the following dropdown menu with two menuItems:

```
<h:form id="form1">
        <p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="emp" value="#{adminBean.employees}"
            selectionMode="single" scrollable="true"
            selection="#{adminBean.selectedEmployee}" rowKey="#{emp.id}">

            <f:facet name="header">Employees

            <h:form>
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

                    <p:menuButton value="Add new Employee">
                        <p:menuitem value="Add Hourly" url="/faces/addHourly.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-plus"/>
                        <p:separator />
                        <p:menuitem value="Add Flat" url="/faces/addFlat.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-plus"/>   
                    </p:menuButton>
                </h:form>

            </f:facet>
...
...
...
```

The problem is that when I click for istance on the `Add Hourly` menuItem, I can get to the `addHourly.xhtml` page correctly, but when I come back to my main page, the address bar of browser remains with the url `/faces/addHourly.xhtml` so if I refresh the page I always go to `/faces/addHourly.xhtml`.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Nested forms are not allowed, not in jsf, not in plain html. Start by correcting that first!

Comment: I eliminated the nested form, but the problem is still there

Comment: The 'homepage' menuitem in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menuButton.xhtml works for me. Clicking it brings me to that corresponding page and pressing back in the browser shows me http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menuButton.xhtml again. So please  be more specific in your problem

Comment: I do not have an homepage button. My problem is not in the "navigation system" but it's in the address bar of the browser. I think that it's impossibile to explain better than I did

Comment: What is shown in the address bar is related to the navigation system e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451 and you have a kind of homepage, at least the code is the same. So unless you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, I'd say 'works for me' (showcase runs latest PF, what do you run), and _"but when I come back to my main page"_ is not specific... HOW do you navigate back? With a 'post' like in the link I provided in this comment?

Comment: I come back with a "back" button, but when I come back the address bar remain on the "addHourly" page, so that if I refresh the page I go to addhourly page. I cannot explain better

Comment: As I expected, your problem IS with the navigation system. It is with 99% certainty what is described in the question I referred to above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)